# Flow rollup, react and babel TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, flowtype, rollup

I'm trying to use `flow`, `babel` and `rollup`, but my code breaks when adding flow. I have tried the `rollup-plugin-flow` and the different `babel-..-..` flow plugins (current implementation), but I'm still getting the same error.

When I check the console. I get the following: ()I can't figure out what I'm missing)

```bash
(!) Missing exports
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
src/components/ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary.js
createElement is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js
26:       if (this.state.errorInfo) {
27:
28:         return React.createElement(
                         ^
29:           'div',
30:           null,
```

**rollup.config.dev.js**

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import cjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import visualize from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: true
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      exclude: [
      'node_modules/**',
      '**/*.scss'
      ],
      presets: [
        [ "env", { "modules": false } ],
        "react"
      ],
      "plugins": [ ["external-helpers"], ["transform-flow-strip-types"], ["syntax-flow"] ]
    }),
    replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development') }),
    scss({
      output: 'dist/style.css'
    }),
    resolve(),
    cjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
...ommited_code
}
```

**ErrorBoundary.js**

```jsx
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component { //<= it breaks here
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    this.setState({ error: error, errorInfo: errorInfo })
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    if (this.state.errorInfo) {

      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Oops something crashed </h2>
            <details style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', color: 'red' }}>
              {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
              <br />
              {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
            </details>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue belongs to your `React` *import*. Since `react` module has `export default` you dont need to import it as you do. It can be simple:

`import React from 'react' // and then you can use as you use`

When you do `import * as React from 'react` it means that you are grabbing all exports `default & simple exports` and store it in a `React` variable. Then to get an access to React itself you should use it as `React.React`.

Please take a look how [`import/export`](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) works.

Comment: thanks,  that fixed the problem and thanks for the link.  I'm just getting confused because the `flow` documentation tells me import `React` as a namespace [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/)

Comment: @intercoder Flow doc is pretty lagging stuff. Always expect it to be out of date. I would not recommend it as a source of truth for ES6 knowledge, since it can't even be a source of truth for Flow itself.